# didMoveToSuperview not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am adding a `UIScrollView` to a UIView.

`willMoveToSuperview:` on the scrollview gets called, but for some reason `didMoveToSuperview:` on the scrollview does not get called, even though the scrollview clearly gets added.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious?

Comment: do you have code implementation to help your question?

Comment: Can you show us your code? I think you've mistyped the method signature.

Comment: ozgur, you got it. I had copied and pasted from "willMoveToSuperview" which has the superview as a parameter, but didMoveToSuperview does not.  Put it as an answer and I'll accept. (I feel stupid)  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably mistyped [the method signature](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622433-didmovetosuperview?language=objc):

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
  [super didMoveToSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although strictly speaking I don't think it requires the call to super, because the original does nothing. From the docs (for UIView at least): "The default implementation of this method does nothing."  Then again, it might be good practice to do this, because one day you might be subclassing something that requires the call to super.

Comment: @narco it is not required but it is a good practice to call super class's implementation for obvious reasons you've already mentioned in your comment.